Problemas al subir imágenes a mi servidor en el sistema operativo IOS
Tengo una aplicación web hecha con react.  Y estoy teniendo problemas para subir imágenes a mi servidor en dispositivos IOS usando el navegador (Safari o Chrome). Estoy usando el siguiente código para cargar las imágenes.
<button onClick={() => document.getElementById('camara').click()} style={{position:'relative',bottom:'10px'}}>Seleccionar Fotos</button>

    <input type="file" id='camara' hidden multiple  accept="image/*"
        onChange={(e) => convertImage(e)}/>

    <div id="customFileLabel" style={{}}>
        {imagen.length === 0
            ? '     Ninguna foto seleccionada'
            : `  Archivos seleccionados: ${imagen.length}`}
        </div>


Y esto para subirlas a mi servidor:
async function registrarImagenes (CodAnuncio){
    imagenesOrdenadas.current.map(async (item,index)  => {
            const CodAnuncioS = JSON.parse(CodAnuncio);
            const imgFinal = document.getElementById('canvas-'+item.id);

            let fd = new FormData() 

            fd.append("pidanuncio",CodAnuncioS)
            fd.append("isportada",index)
            fd.append("imagenbs4", imgFinal.toDataURL("image/webp"))
            const res = await axios.post('https://merkasa.online/api/ApiRegistroAnuncioImgf.php', fd);
            }
}

He probado que funciona bien en computadoras de escritorio y en dispositivos Android con la mayoría de los navegadores convencionales, el problema solo es con dispositivos IOS y MAC.  La parte del backend está bien.  Sospecho que la falla está en las restricciones que hace IOS al acceder a los archivos del celular, pero no sé cómo superar esas restricciones, si debo usar algún componente especializado para esto o no.

Me parece que la explicación que das no deja ver claramente el problema que tienes. Quizás falta explicar cómo el código falla o qué es exactamente lo que esperas que pase y no está pasando, o si tienes un mensaje de error, cuál es ese error exactamente y en qué momento ocurre. Para más información lee [ask].
